# Apache Flink and Delta Connector - Metrics not Incrementing

Tags: apache-flink

I am using [Flink](https://flink.apache.org/) `1.15.3` and its respective [Delta Connector](https://github.com/delta-io/connectors/tree/master/flink). End-to-End, the application is working as expected. No error logs, however I receive a warning log with the following:

```
Name collision: Group already contains a Metric with the name 'DeltaSinkBytesWritten'. Metric will not be reported.[xxx, flink, operator]

Name collision: Group already contains a Metric with the name 'DeltaSinkRecordsWritten'. Metric will not be reported.[xxx, flink, operator]
```

As a result, those above mentioned metrics do not get reported/incremented. How can I potentially get around this or investigate further? This assumes that my application may potentially not be setup correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug on the Delta Connector for Flink:
https://github.com/delta-io/connectors/issues/493